# Post a binary file using Python3 basic library

Tags: python-3.x

I want to upload a xml file in binary mode using Python 3 Basic Libraries. 
Actually I need to upload it through a http post request.
I don't want to use any other external library for this.
Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Upload an XML file to what? A server? If so, then **yes**, it is possible. Consider [**ftplib**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html), a basic library (comes with vanilla python). Read the documentation there -- it supports binary mode uploads.

Comment: Actually I need to upload it through a http post request.